# Getting string value displayed in Textview of appWidget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, textview

I have an appWidget which displays a text view, in which the text is set from another activity via RemoteViews. Now i need to use or get the text that is displayed in this widget. How can i do this?

```
String text = context.getText(R.id.widgetVerse).toString();
```

Gives me "false" lol! although that was a try...

By the way i need to send this string to another intent via putExtra.

Comment: Similar problem.[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748161/how-can-get-text-of-textview-that-placed-on-a-widget-in-android-programming/9751614#9751614

Comment: possible duplicate of [get text of a TextView in android home widget (not in activity)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237217/get-text-of-a-textview-in-android-home-widget-not-in-activity)

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

String text = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.widgetVerse)).getText().toString() ;